# How do sides of a constant area quadrilateral rotate?

Tags: trigonometry

A quadrilateral of constant area having  three fixed length sides $(a,c,b)$ has fourth side length variable. End coordinates of fixed side length  $c$ are $(0,0),(c,0)$.

Find relation between angles $ (x,y).$

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be the constant area of the quadrilateral.  We consider the right trapezoid obtained by projecting the vertices of the variable edge on the horizontal line.  We have then
$$
S = \frac{1}{2}[(a\sin x +b\sin y)(c -a\cos x +b\cos y) +a^2\sin x \cos x -b^2\sin y\cos y],
$$
hence the relation
$$
a\sin x +b\sin y = \frac{2S}{c}. 
$$

Comment: OK.  I deleted it.